# How to use $(OutDir) in Pre-Build Event?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, tfsbuild

`$(OutDir) = \bin\Release (in local with VS2012)`

`$(OutDir) = C:\\...\BuildDefinition\Binaries (on TFS2010 Team Build)`

How to do in a Pre-build event to write a XCOPY which works in the two cases ?

In my project2, I reference the project1. So I need to do this :

In local :

`XCOPY  /Y  $(SolutionDir)Project1\$(OutDir)Project1.dll"`

`"$(SolutionDir)MyProject2\Objects\Assemblies"`

On Team Build

`XCOPY  /Y  "$(OutDir)Project1.dll"  "$(SolutionDir)Project2\Objects\Assemblies"`

Thank you.

Comment: If you reference the project why can't you just set *CopyLocal* to true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a useful build event check:

```
if "$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)" == ""
```

this will allow you to define a build event for when your in visual studio, not when running on TeamBuild(msbuild)

Answer (score 2):

As a best practice you should not call XCOPY from your TFS build or Visual Studio in a pre-build target for a needed DLL reference.

Create a project reference in project 2 to project 1. This will ensure that the latest code is compiled and referenced correctly.

TFS will automatically take care of moving the dll for you. Visual Studio will automatically know how to find it as well and will move both dlls to your output folder if you set the reference to copy local.

If you have a 3rd party dll that you are not compiling then best practice is to create a folder called lib\ or dependencies\ and reference the dll's from that location.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you but I can't do that. I reference a SQLCLR project and in VS2012, we can't reference the project. The build fail. So in my Database project, I reference a SQLCLR assembly copied from the SQLCLR project to a folder of my Database project, with a pre-build event.

Comment: You should still be able to reference the SQLCLR as a project reference in your database project. If your build is failing then it sounds like you have other issues. Regardless it appears you found what you need.